# -jar command the terminal gives me "-bash: -jar: command not found" but I have current java version

Tags: java, jar, terminal

**I type in a -jar command such as *-jar MakeAppTouchTestable.jar* and I am given the message below:**

-bash: -jar: command not found

**I used "*java -version*" to find if I had java in the first place:**

java version "1.7.0_51"
Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_51-b13)
Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.51-b03, mixed mode)

**I am not sure what to do at this point.**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Type

```
java -jar MakeAppTouchTestable.jar
```

because `-jar` isn't a command; it's a command-line option of `java` command.

Answer (score 1):

The command should surely be `jar`, not `-jar`. e.g.

```
jar tf MakeAppTouchTestable.jar
```

If you are trying to run an executable jar, the command is `java` with `-jar` as an argument e.g.

```
java -jar MakeAppTouchTestable.jar
```